# Prove that the collection of images is a set

Tags: set-theory

For the first part of Exercise 8 in *Daniel W. Cunningham. "Set Theory: A First Course."*:

> Let $R$ be a relation and $\mathcal{G}$ be a set. Prove that $\{ R[C]: C \in \mathcal{G} \}$ is a set.

I can see that there's a one-to-one correspondence between $C$ and $R[C]$, or in symbols:

$(\forall C \in \mathcal{G})\exists! R[C]$.

So, my intention is to apply the Replacement Axiom to complete the the proof. However, the axiom requires a formula $\phi(C, R[C])$, that the above statement doesn't have, such that:

$(\forall C \in \mathcal{G})\exists! R[C]\phi(C, R[C])$.

Setting $\phi(C, R[C])=C = C \vee R[C] = R[C]$ seems good but I'm not sure that it's valid to consider $C \text{ and } R[C]$ free variables of $\phi$ anymore or there's a better way to prove this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that $\exists! R[C]$ is not a correct way to use the (unique) existential quantifier. Quantifiers should always bind variables, not terms like $R[C]$, and they should be followed by a formula.

The correct way to write "every set in $\mathcal{G}$ has a unique image under $R$" is $\forall C\in \mathcal{G}\,\exists! I\, (I=R[C])$.

Now you can see that your formula should be $\varphi(C,I)\colon I=R[C]$, which, if you like, you can expand out using the definition of image: $\forall y\, (y\in I \leftrightarrow \exists x\,(x\in C\land (x,y)\in R)$.

Comment: just one small stuff: In $\forall C\in \mathcal{G}\,\exists I\, (I=R[C])$, using $\exists$ instead of $\exists!$ is intentional or a typo, in this particular case (i.e $R[C]$ can be shown to be unique)?

Comment: @TranKhanh Typo. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & edit. However, the Replacement Axiom can be written as (note the $\exists x \in A$ instead of $\exists! x \in A$): $\forall A((\forall x \in A)\exists!y\psi(x, y) \to \exists S \forall y(y\in S \leftrightarrow (\exists x \in A)\psi(x, y)))$, despite $y$ is uniquely connected to $x$ in the axiom. I'm not sure if it's valid to do the same thing here (i.e. like what you wrote before the edit) or it's a different situation?

Comment: @TranKhanh I think you're confusing yourself. We want to apply the Axiom of Replacement to the formula $\varphi(x,y)\colon y = R[x]$ and the set $\mathcal{G}$. In order to apply the Axiom, we need to prove the hypothesis, which is $\forall x\in \mathcal{G}\, \exists! y\, \varphi(x,y)$. This says "$\varphi(x,y)$ defines a function with domain $\mathcal{G}$". Once we've proven this, we can then conclude $\exists S\forall y\, (y\in S\leftrightarrow \exists x\in \mathcal{G}\, \varphi(x,y))$. This says "There exists a set $S$ which is the image of $\mathcal{G}$ under the function $\varphi$".

Comment: We need to use the unique existential quantifier $\exists!$ to express "$\varphi(x,y)$ defines a function", but we don't need to use it to express "$S$ is the image of $\mathcal{G}$ under this function". It might also be confusing you that there are two levels of "image" going on here: We're taking the image of $\mathcal{G}$ under the function defined by, for each set in $G$, taking the image of that set under the relation $R$.